# Android AlertDialog.Builder OnClickListener on custom button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I would like to display my omn Alert Dialog. I created the layout and then used it on a OnClickListener. (when you click on an element of a list, it displays details about it)

When the AlertDialog appears, all is fine but I would like that my own Dismiss button works. Sadly it doesn't and I don't know how to manage this.

This is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/DetailDialog"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/popup_background" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dismissAlert"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/firstDivider"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/popup_background"
    android:text="Dismiss"
    android:textColor="@color/splashColor" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alertDetail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="Description : alert&apos;s details"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/firstDivider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/alertDetail"
    android:background="@color/design_alert" />
```

And a part of my code

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                           this.messageDialog("Order " + string + " is waiting for a time estimate", OrderAlertsPage.this);     

                        }

                        public void messageDialog(String message, final Context activity) {
                            //On instancie notre layout en tant que View
                            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
                            final View alertDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_detail_dialog, null);

                            //Création de l'AlertDialog
                            final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                            adb.setView(alertDialogView);

                            TextView text = (TextView) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.alertDetail);
                            text.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
                            text.setText(message);
                            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                            Button dismiss = (Button) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dismissAlert);
                            dismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                ((DialogInterface) adb).dismiss(); // I can't do it..


                                }
                            });


                            adb.show();

                        }
                    });
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: idea which you specified is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `dismiss()` on the dialog, not the builder.

For example,

```
final AlertDialog dlg = adb.show();

// in onClick()
dlg.dismiss();
```

Comment: Thank you @laalto ! 

I was not careful, it was a stupid mistake. 

thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Dismiss",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

You can try this:

```
dismiss.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_detail_dialog);

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        text.setText(message);
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        Button dismiss = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dismissAlert);
        dismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  dialog.dismiss();
             }
        });

dialog.show();
```